# How to check if a Street Side (or Street View) exist for a coordinate in Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps, bing

I am trying to create a custom control in Angular on the Map. The control will display a button on top of a Map and when user drops the mouse anywhere in map, if the street side exists for that coordinate on map, then street view should be loaded.

Otherwise the user should be prompted a message that "No street side exists for the chosen point"

How can check that street side exists or not using Bing Maps API.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-imagery-metadata

Specifically, you can request the Streetside Imagery metadata to determine the availability of Streetside at a location at a specified zoom level (and the vintage of said imagery):

```
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Metadata/{imagerySet}/{centerPoint}?orientation={orientation}&zoomLevel={zoomLevel}&include={ImageryProviders}&key={BingMapsAPIKey}
```

From the examples:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/MetaData/Streetside/47.668687,-122.384795?key={BingMapsAPIKey}
```

This returns the following info:

```
{
    "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
    "brandLogoUri": "http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
    "resourceSets": [
        {
            "estimatedTotal": 1,
            "resources": [
                {
                    "__type": "StreetsideMetadata:http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/search\/local\/ws\/rest\/v1",
                    "imageHeight": 256,
                    "imageUrl": "http:\/\/ecn.{subdomain}.tiles.virtualearth.net\/tiles\/hs0203232101212100{faceId}{tileId}?g=7467&key=AmXtaLCMP57QEyxyjkcduZRBnG2QsKlj-iI5ng6neAGhOFP1md5I_S6iJzyO8GcF",
                    "imageUrlSubdomains": [
                        "t0",
                        "t1",
                        "t2",
                        "t3"
                    ],
                    "imageWidth": 256,
                    "imageryProviders": null,
                    "vintageEnd": "17 Jul 2014 GMT",
                    "vintageStart": "17 Jul 2014 GMT",
                    "zoomMax": 4,
                    "zoomMin": 1,
                    "he": 52.286,
                    "lat": 47.668696,
                    "lon": -122.384813,
                    "pi": 0.638,
                    "ro": -0.326
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "statusCode": 200,
    "statusDescription": "OK",
    "traceId": "d5b39048afed42d29841380a6f57bed1|CO0000112F|7.7.0.0"
}
```

Comment: With this API, I am getting Metadata for street side for coordinates which don't have  street side. How to validate that the point clicked on map does not have a street side.